# Merge code across two Azure DevOps Team Projects

Tags: azure-devops, branching-and-merging, promotion-code, team-project

We have two separate team projects (Let's call them Staging and Prod) within our single Azure DevOps Organisation. Currently, both team project code bases are nearly identical. However, we've decided to use Staging to develop and test all of our changes and once successfully verified, we promote/merge the code across to the Prod team project.

For example:

```
[[ Staging Team Project ]]
File A - v1.1 - (latest changes, tested, verified and ready for promotion to Prod.)
File B - v3.2 - (latest changes, tested, verified and ready for promotion to Prod.)


[[ Prod Team Project ]]
File A - v1.0 - (last release currently in Live.)
File B - v3.1 - (last release currently in Live.)
```

Using the above as an example, is there a way to carry out this code promotion/merge of the two files from the Staging team project to Prod, or is our only option to perform a manual merge externally, using something like Beyond Compare and then check the merge into the Prod repository?

Comment: This is possible, but only if you use TFVC as source control system. if you use git you'd have to fall back to some external stuff

Answer (score 1):

Pull request can be created between branches in same repo or from forked repo, but cannot be created between different repos in two projects.

As an alternative, you can create a new branch `temp` based on `Prod` repo branch, replace the files(you can checkout/checkin on local machine to replace, or directly upload files to replace on Azure DevOps UI), then create a pull request from `temp` branch to `Prod` branch to validate and merge accordingly.

Comment: Wade Zhou........is your suggestion possible across two team projects though? Please note, that is the critical point made on this entire issue - it is not a merging of code across two repos of the same team project. The team projects in our case are separate.

Comment: Hi @hitman126, as i stated, the workaround is to put codes in same repo with two branches, you cannot merge code between different repros without any relationship directly.